# Set-Cookie response header does not set a browser cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, setcookie

I have a problem with setting a cookie after user login. (This problem is only in production).
My /login endpoint returns a cookie with token and other required info (below)

```
if (isPasswordValid === true) {
        jwt.sign({ username, id: userDoc._id }, secret, (error, token) => {
          if (error) throw error;
          res.cookie("token", token, { 
            httpOnly: true, 
            domain: "https://my-frontend-url.com",
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
          }).status(200).json({
            message: "User have been logged in successfully",
            id: userDoc._id,
            username,
            authorname: userDoc.authorname,
          });
        });
```

Then I fetch the endpoint from the client:

```
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`, {
      method: "post",
      credentials: "include", 
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password,
      }),
    });
```

After I get a 200 status, and Set-Cookie response header contains the token, but it also has a warning: "This attempt to set a cookie via Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url."

I am also using cookie-parcer middleware: `app.use(cookieParser());` and cors middleare `app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: ["https://my-frontend-url.com", "http://localhost:3000"], }));` But still cannot figure out the solution.

I have tried to set `credentials: "include",` to the fetch request.
I have trind to use cors: `app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: ["https://my-frontend-url.com", "http://localhost:3000"], }));`
I have also tried to configure the res.cookie: `res.cookie("token", token, {  httpOnly: true,  domain: "https://my-frontend-url.com", sameSite: "none", secure: true, })`
But non of it helped. Would love to get some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set Domain option to

```
{ domain: ".my-frontend-url.com" }
```